# C++ Custom Class is not being recognized by other classes

Tags: c++

I have Road and Car classes that are in their own .cpp and .h files. 
I include the .h file for the Road class in the Car header. 
I am using the Road class as a parameter for functions in the Car classes.
I have static variables in the car class I need access to in the road class.

The compiler is not recognizing the Road type in the Car Class, and I can't figure out why.

Road.h

```
#ifndef ROAD_H
#define ROAD_H

#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"

using namespace std;

class Road
{
public:
  // class functions
private:
  // member variables
};

#endif
```

Car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <iostream>
#include "road.h"

using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
  // class functions
  void enter_a_road(Road& r1, const short left_pos);
private:
  // member variables
};

#endif
```

Error Message:

```
In file included from Road.h:11:0,
                 from Road.cpp:6:
Car.h:68:23: error: 'Road' has not been declared
     void enter_a_road(Road& r1, const short left_pos);
                       ^
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: [You have a circular dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Comment: road includes car and car includes road includes car includes road includes car...

Comment: You are including car.h in road.h, and road.h in car.h. This is not possible.

Comment: You most likely have a circular dependency. Car needs to know about road, and road needs to know about Car. (At least I assume you have a `Car` somewhere inside `class Road`

Comment: What you should try to solve this conundrum is to use [forward declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/96780).

Comment: Try this: `void enter_a_road(class Road& r1, const short left_pos);`

Comment: In addition to forward declarations, you should use either header guards `#ifndef SOME_KEY_WORD  ..... #endif` or `#pragma once`.  Either (both are extraneous) will prevent circular dependency from biting you.

Comment: I forgot to show that I had #ifndef ... #endif in the headers. Too second nature for me to think about them; I edited the code in the question to include the fact I have included this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. The quickest way to solve it is to use a [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/96780).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Road;

class Car
{
public:
  // class functions
  void enter_a_road(Road& r1, const short left_pos);
private:
  // member variables
};
```

This is acceptable because the compiler doesn't need to know about the internal structure of `Road` in order to compile the function declaration.

The same could probably be done in the `Road.h`, though I don't know why the include is there to begin with.

Comment: I have static variables about the Car class I need access to in the Road class is the reason I have car included in road.

Comment: @Bristles I'm sure why this is the case.  It is difficult to know from your posted code.  Consider having the `Road` class access these properties via *getter* functions exposed in `Car`.

Comment: @AndrewFalanga That would still require the inclusion of the Car.h file in Road.h

Comment: @Bristles Only if you made calls to those *getters* from within the header file.  This usually isn't the case.